# UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet in modal view

Tags: ios, ipad, uialertview, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

I am trying to show a UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet anchored to a toolbar button. I have searched the web and found out I have to do this:

```
alertController.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = myButton;
```

however this does not work for me. The UIAlertController is shown as on iPhone on the iPad. Centered in the bottom middle of the window.

Here is my code:

```
// create action sheet
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"test title" message:nil
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

// Delete Button
UIAlertAction *actionDelete = [UIAlertAction
                actionWithTitle:@"button"
                style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                    // Delete
                }];

// Cancel Button
UIAlertAction *actionCancel = [UIAlertAction
                actionWithTitle:@"Avbryt"
                style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                    // Cancel code
                }];

// Add Cancel action
[alertController addAction:actionCancel];
[alertController addAction:actionDelete];

// show action sheet
alertController.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = self.downloadAllButton;
alertController.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
[alertController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

By the way I am doing this in a Document Provider extension in the Documentpicker. So the UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet is in a modal view already. I gues this is my problem, but I can not figure out how to change this for the iPad. This drives me crazy!!! Please Help!!

Regards,
Markus

Comment: Try removing the line `[alertController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];`. I show an alert on an iPad from a toolbar and I don't use such a line.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But this does not fix the problem. I guess the problem is that since the UIAlertController is in a modal view controller (the documentpicker) the view it is in is so small the UIAlertController thinks it is on a iPhone? Hwo to override this behaviour?